# Managing Azure CosmosDB Account in terraform - state doesnt get updated properly after apply

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, terraform-provider-azure

I am managing a CosmosDB account in Terraform, but every time I plan it wants to set the `default_identity_type`.  When I apply this, the state file doesn't reflect the change - therefore on subsequent plans it tries to apply the same change again.

The actual resource in Azure has existed for some time, and I imported the state using `terraform import ...`.  The state looks like this (with sensitive values removed):

```
{
      "module": "module.main",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "azurerm_cosmosdb_account",
      "name": "root",
      "provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm\"]",
      "instances": [
        {
          "schema_version": 0,
          "attributes": {
            "access_key_metadata_writes_enabled": true,
            "analytical_storage": [
              {
                "schema_type": ""
              }
            ],
            "analytical_storage_enabled": false,
            "backup": [
              {
                "interval_in_minutes": 1440,
                "retention_in_hours": 48,
                "storage_redundancy": "Geo",
                "type": "Periodic"
              }
            ],
            "capabilities": [
              {
                "name": "EnableServerless"
              }
            ],
            "capacity": [],
            "consistency_policy": [
              {
                "consistency_level": "Session",
                "max_interval_in_seconds": 5,
                "max_staleness_prefix": 100
              }
            ],
            "cors_rule": [],
            "create_mode": "",
            "default_identity_type": "",
            "enable_automatic_failover": false,
            "enable_free_tier": false,
            "enable_multiple_write_locations": false,
            "geo_location": [
              {
                "failover_priority": 0,
                "location": "northeurope",
                "prefix": "",
                "zone_redundant": false
              }
            ],
            "identity": [],
            "ip_range_filter": "",
            "is_virtual_network_filter_enabled": false,
            "key_vault_key_id": null,
            "kind": "GlobalDocumentDB",
            "local_authentication_disabled": false,
            "location": "northeurope",
            "mongo_server_version": null,
            "network_acl_bypass_for_azure_services": false,
            "network_acl_bypass_ids": [],
            "offer_type": "Standard",
            "public_network_access_enabled": true,
            "resource_group_name": "dev",
            "restore": [],
            "timeouts": {
              "create": null,
              "delete": null,
              "read": null,
              "update": null
            },
            "virtual_network_rule": []
          },
          "sensitive_attributes": [],
          "dependencies": [
            "module.main.azurerm_resource_group.main",
            "module.main.azurerm_resource_group.root"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

So when I `plan` I get:
[update in-place warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fveyv.png)

My terraform is very basic, as I'm just using the default values for most properties:

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "root" {
  name                  = "some-name"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.root.location
  offer_type            = "Standard"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.root.name
  kind                  = "GlobalDocumentDB"

  geo_location {
    failover_priority   = 0
    location            = azurerm_resource_group.root.location
  }

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level   = "Session"
  }

  tags                  = merge(var.tags, var.cosmosdb_account_tags)
}
```

There have been issues raised surrounding the use of `default_identity_type` recently and updates to the AzureRM provider (up to version 2.90) but I'm still experiencing this issue.

Does anyone have any workarounds for this?

Comment: hello @rick , can you please share the screen shot of what is getting forced replaced in that cosmos db account when you do a plan ?

Comment: hello @AnsumanBal-MT - there is a screen shot of the plan within my initial question, it's a link...

Answer (score 0):

My reputation does not allow me to comment, but usually, when Terraform insists on changing a resource, it will tell you what the current value of the property is and what it wants to change it to. (usually `null`)

As a workaround, try to add the property `default_identity_type` and set it to whatever value Terraform says it has, and then run a plan again to see if it changes the behavior.

EDIT: I just had a look at the screenshot. So the value you should set as a workaround is `"FirstPartyIdentity"`

Looking at the documentation it should be optional, but obviously it is not. Maybe this is an error in the documentation.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cosmosdb_account

Comment: Even if you are not setting the `default_identity_type` as `firstparty identity` , terraform uses that as a default value for the argument . and optional means that you can set it to any value  from the allowed types if you want otherwise it will use the default value i.e. firstpartyidentity

Comment: I have tried expicitly setting `default_identity_type` to its default value of `FirstPartyIdentity` but that makes no difference